# File redirection for loops in the shell

Tags: shell, awk, stdin, io-redirection

I was trying to understand how the file redirection for the loops work in the shell, so I wrote the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS='' read -r line; do
  echo 'reading '$line
  awk -F, '{sub(/.*/,"Completed",$2);print}'
done<$1
```

I gave the following input file to the script:

```
hello,hi,how are you
i,am,good
```

The output of running the script on the above file is:

```
reading hello,hi,how are you
i Completed good
```

I was expecting an output of the form:

```
reading hello,hi,how are you
hello,Completed,how are you
i Completed good
reading i,am,good
hello,Completed,how are you
i Completed good
```

Why is the loop not printing "reading" for both the lines? And, why is the replacement with awk not happening for the first line? Could anyone please explain the output of the script?

Comment: Your `awk` command will read from standard input, which in this case is the redirection of `$1`: so `read` reads the first line of `$1`, and then `awk` reads the remaining lines. Maybe you want `awk -F, '{sub(/.*/,"Completed",$2);print}' <<< "$line"` to send the content of `$line` to `awk`.

Comment: why this comment is not an answer? :)

Comment: Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one `stdin` that you redirect in the loop. Both `read` and `awk` will read from that `stdin`. While the `read` only consumes one line (the first), `awk` happily consumes the rest.

In the next iteration, `read` has nothing more to read and the loop terminates.

If you want to provide data on `awk`'s stdin, you must do so explicitly, e.g. by piping into `awk` with `printf '%s\n' "$line" | awk ...`.